# Use Optional instead of null check

Tags: java, null, java-stream, option-type

I have to check if an attribute of an object is null or not. Depending on the above check I have to update another attribute in the same object. Is it possible to use Optional class and its methods to replace null checks?

```
if(userData.getSubscription()==null){
    userData.setFees(Enum.ZERO);
} else {
    userData.setFees(Enum.HUNDRED);
}
```

Let me know if this can be replaced with a single line using Java 8 Optional class or other features.

Comment: I'm not up on `Optional` idioms so won't post an *answer*, but if you're looking for a single statement rather than an `if`/`else`, you don't need `Optional` for that: `userData.setFees(userData.getSubscription() == null ? Enum.ZERO : Enum.HUNDRED);` Easier to debug, though, with the `if`/`else` or at least two statements: `Enum fees = userData.getSubscription() == null ? Enum.ZERO : Enum.HUNDRED; userData.setFees(fees);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want:
`userData.setFees(Objects.isNull(userData.getSubscription()) ? Enum.ZERO : Enum.HUNDRED)`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
Optional::ofNullable(userData.getSubscription()).map(any -> Enum.HUNDRED).orElse(Enum.ZERO);
```

However I don't see much benefit to that over @T.J. Crowder's suggestion from the comments

```
userData.getSubscription() == null ? Enum.ZERO : Enum.HUNDRED
```

Answer (score 0):

The main use of `Optional` is to prevent you from forgetting to check for `null`. Thus, it would only be useful if the `Optional` type was returned from `getSubscription()`. Then you could do:

```
userData.setFees(userData.getSubscription().map(x -> Enum.HUNDRED).orElse(Enum.ZERO));
```

But if you can't or don't want to change `getSubscription()` to return `Optional`, then there is no point in using `Optional` here. Just do this:

```
userData.setFees(userData.getSubscription() == NULL ? Enum.ZERO : Enum.HUNDRED);
```

By the way, if `Enum.ZERO` and `Enum.HUNDRED` are just names representing 0 and 100, then that's not a good idea. The words "ZERO" and "HUNDRED" are just as much a "magic number" as the numbers 0 and 100 themselves. You should name your enums something descriptive like "FREE_OF_CHARGE" and "FULL_PRICE".